# How to implement zendesk web widget to specific page on gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, zendesk

Adding zendesk install script to the `html.js` file is working as expected and the widget is showing on all pages.

I want to show it on specific page like `about-us` page.
I have tried this

```
render() {
return (
<>
<script
    id="ze-snippet"
    src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=xxx-xxxxx"
>
</script>
...
</>
```

But it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In index.html file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- your scripts -->

        <script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key={YOUR_KEY}"> </script>
        <!-- Hide de widget by default -->
        <script>zE('webWidget', 'hide')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your component(s) to show

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        // show widget on mount component
        zE('webWidget', 'show')
    }

    componentDidUnmount () {
        // hide widget on unmount component
        zE('webWidget', 'hide')
    }

    render () {
        // your render
        return (
            <div>Hello World</div>
        )
    }
}
```

In other components nothing need to do

Answer (score 1):

To add `<scripts>` in your page with React (and so, with Gatsby) you have several options. The easiest to implement is using the `<Helmet>` component. You can check for further information in [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet). Basically, it handles your `<head>` tag:

> This reusable React component will manage all of your changes to the
> document head.
>
> Helmet takes plain HTML tags and outputs plain HTML tags. It's dead
> simple and React beginner-friendly.

To show this script only in /about-us page, you need to insert this snippet in your desired page:

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const AboutUs= () => (
 <>
   <>
      <Helmet>
        <script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=xxx-xxxxx">
      </Helmet>
   </>
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="About us" />
     <h1>I'm the about page</h1>
    </Layout>
 </>  
 )

export default AboutUs
```

It doesn't matter if you have a stateful or a stateless component, the idea is to wrap between `<Helmet>` component anything that you want to be placed in your `<head>`, in this case, a `<script>`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
In this way, it works fine on `about-us` page.
But when you go to the landing page or another, the widget is still there which isn't expected.

Comment: I guess it's because it's inside <Layout> component which is shared among pages. I've updated my answer with another guess. Let me know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

React functions

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        window.zE('webWidget', 'show')
        return () => window.zE('webWidget', 'hide')
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>Hello World</div>
    )
}
```